# Javascript Function Ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, dimple.js

I have a basic question about how javascript functions execute within HTML. I'm creating a graph with dimple.js and want to select an svg element once the graph has been created via javascript. However, even when my jQuery selector is the very last bit of script on my page, it won't execute because the dimple graph hasn't actually been created. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(data) {

          "use strict";
          var margin = 75,
              width = 1400 - margin,
              height = 600 - margin;

          d3.select("body")
            .append("h2")
            .text("World Cup Attendance")

          var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width + margin)
              .attr("height", height + margin)
            .append('g')
                .attr('class','chart');

          var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
          var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "year"); 
          myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "attendance");
          x.dateParseFormat = "%Y";
          x.tickFormat = "%Y";
          x.timeInterval = 4;
          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
          myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.scatter);
          myChart.draw();
        };

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", draw);
  debugger
  $('.example').doSomething();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I assumed the page and graph would be fully loaded where I placed the debugger statement at the bottom because that's the last line of code. However when the page pauses there the graph hasn't actually been created. After the debugger line the page runs through a bunch of functions in the dimple library to create the svg graph. Obviously the jQuery line right after doesn't work because there's no element to select yet.

I think I'm missing something fundamental when it comes to javascript. How do I get my jQuery to run only *after* dimple has done its thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supplying the `draw` function as a callback to the CSV request.

The drawing is done when `draw` is done. So put it there, or create a little anonymous function that calls them in sequence, e.g.,

```
d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", function() {
  draw();
  $('.example').doSomething();
);
```

(If D3/Dimple's chart `draw()` function is also async then you'd need to do it in *that* callback, if it has one, but I don't know Dimple.)

Comment: It's not asynchronous, your answer is correct - except that the d3.tsv callback needs a data parameter which would then need to be passed into the draw function (the one in the example not the dimple draw function).

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I passed in the data parameter. For anyone who stumbles across this:
d3.tsv("world_cup.tsv", function(data) {
  draw(data);
  $('.example').doSomething();
});